# Monic quadratic diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ be given. When does

$$x^2+ax+b=0$$
have a solution in the integers? Can we say more if we want $x$ to be a **square** ?

From the Rational Root Test we can say that any rational solution  $x$ must be an integer and  $x \mid b$. Looking at the quadratic formula we see that
$$-\frac{a}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-b} $$
must be integral as well. However this doesn't seem very kind of enlightening.

Comment: There is an integer solution if there are integers $r,s$ such that $a+r+s=0$ and $rs=b$. I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect there to be.

Comment: @Gerry basically that means take two conjugated divisors of $b$, if their sum is $-a$ then there is a solution (i.e. these divisors), yet I agree we are not much more advanced...

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'd like some criterion or at least neccesary condition on $a,b$.

Comment: You can't really do better than the quadratic formula here, the condition is just that the discriminant is a (rational) square. You can think about the case $a = 0$ to see why you can't do better than this.

Comment: To expand on Qiaochu Yuan's comment; that quadratic has a solution in the integers if and only if
$$4x^2+4ax+4b=0,$$
has a solution in the integers, which is equivalent to
$$(2x+a)^2=a^2-4b.$$
This shows that your quadratic has an integral solution if and only if $a^2-4b$ is a perfect square. That's precisely the condition you found by looking at the quadratic formula.

Comment: It has integer solutions when $\space a\space$ is equal to the sum of integer cofactors of $\space b.$